# Add file names to columns in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am importing a list of several dataframes using a custom function. I want to take the name of the imported file (e.g. `file1` from `file1.csv`) and add it onto all of the column names in that dataframe. In this example, all column names will look like this:

```
# Column names as they are 
  q1 q2 q3 

# Column names with added name of the file they come from    
  q1_file1 q2_file1  q3_file1
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work (the list ends up having 0 dataframes):

```
my_function<- function (x) {
 df <- read.csv(x)
 tag <- sub('\\.csv$', '', x)
 colnames(df) <- paste0(tag, colnames(df))
 }

 lapply(my_list, my_function)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The last assignment in a function will be returned as values if there is no further return argument. Therefore, add one line `return(df)` or just `df` to your function, to return the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be:

```
#Code
tucson_function<- function (x) {
 df <- read.csv(x)
 tag <- sub('\\.csv$', '', x)
 df$tag <- tag
 }
```

Or:

```
#Code
tucson_function<- function (x) {
 df <- read.csv(x)
 tag <- sub('\\.csv$', '', x)
 names(df) <- paste0(tag,'.',names(df))
return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transform` with `tools::file_path_sans_ext` to create a column

```
my_function<- function(x) {
      df <- read.csv(x)
      transform(df, tag = tools::file_path_sans_ext(x))
  }
```

and then call the function with `lapply`

```
lapply(my_list, my_function)
```

---

In the OP's function the issue seems to be that the `return` is the last assignment i.e. the column names assignment.  We need to `return` the data i.e. 'df'

```
my_function<- function (x) {
  df <- read.csv(x)
  tag <- sub('\\.csv$', '', x)
  colnames(df) <- paste0(tag, colnames(df))
  df
 }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you. I am getting the error that `Error: 'file_paths_sans_ext' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tools`

Comment: @salix_august sorry, a typo.  it would be `path` instead of `paths` in `file_path_sans_ext`

Comment: @salix_august as an example `tools::file_path_sans_ext("file1.csv")#
[1] "file1"`